# how to read cell formatting from google sheets? (php)

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My goal is to only retrieve the values of the cells in the spreadsheet if it is a certain color.

I'm reading values from Google Sheets using google-api-php-client and google-api-php-client-services libraries this way:

```
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

Is there a way to retreive what colour a certain cell is?

Comment: Unfortunately the Sheets API does not provide the endpoint to access range properties such as background color. It is however possible to do so with Google Apps Script.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Before I propose a sample script, I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your question is correct. So can I confirm about your situation and goal in your question? 1.You want to retrieve the background color of a cell using Sheets API. 2. You want to achieve this using googleapis with PHP. 3. You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Tanaike yes you're correct abou alll 3!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that you had replied now. I apologize for this. When you replied, please include `@username` in the comment. By this, the user can notice it. In this case, unfortunately, there are no methods for directly searching the background color of the cells in Sheets API. So how about the following flow? 1. Retrieve the background colors from all cells. 2. Retrieve the coordinates of the cells searched by the color you inputted. By this, I think that your goal can be achieved. But if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.